# Whats the chance that upon randomly adding $\pm1$ to a number, it eventually reaches $0$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

Start with an integer $k$. Then at each step either add or substract $1$ randomly, if after some amount of steps you get the number $0$ the process terminates. What's the probability that the process terminates?

There's really not much context, to be honest the question arised while placing garlics on Plants vs. Zombies due to the nature they have. The probability is obviously grater that $1/2^k$ but when trying to find a general rule for each case I get stuck.

If I had to guess, I would guess the probability is $1$, since heuristically this feels like if the process didn't terminate, the partial sums would hover around $k$ and it *feels* likely eventually it would hover far enough

Comment: You do indeed have probability $1$ of hitting the origin. Interestingly, the situation remains the same in two dimensions (on a square grid we move randomly left, right, up, or down), but **changes** in $3$ (and more) dimensions! See [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/PDFs/PCMI/PCMI-notes-1).

Comment: though the expected time to hit $0$ is infinite, even if you start at $k=1$

Comment: Given an infinite number of steps, it is intuitively hard to imagine that the chance of **never** hitting zero would be $> 0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you very much! I assume you are referring to Thm 2.22. This is exactly what I was looking for, it's so cool that it fails for $d\geq3$

Comment: @user2661923 And yet it is once we're in dimension $3$ or greater!